# Как исправить ошибку при подключении пакета nuget?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocad

При добавлении в проект пакета Autocad.Net пишет ошибку:
 Серьезность    Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
    Ошибка

```
    Не удалось установить пакет «AutoCAD.NET 23.0.0». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно получить у автора пакета.
```

Уже несколько версий попробовал до 2 версии framework, Но все равно пишет эту ошибку. Как это исправить?

Comment: У вас проект .NET Core? Тогда используйте пакет AutoCAD.NET.Core.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, У меня Framework, Как я понимаю, это разное. Окей попробую

Comment: Судя по `AutoCAD.NET 23.0.0` `Dependencies .NETFramework 4.7` проект нужно собирать под 4.7